# how do you calculate correlation for some columns in a data frame?

Tags: r

I need to be able to calculate correlation coefficient for a data frame by column. For example, my data frame is this:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Server = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("server101", "server102"), class = "factor"), 
JVM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
.Label = c("JVM1", "JVM2", "JVM3", "JVM4"), 
class = "factor"), cpu = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 20L), 
trans = c(1000L, 2000L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 60L, 30L)),  
.Names = c("Server", "JVM", "cpu", "trans"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I need to be able to calculate the correlation of coefficient between cpu and trans by each jvm and server.

I have tried this:

```
apply(df[,c('trans','cpu')], function(x) FUN=cor(x["trans"],x["cpu"]))
```

any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a base R way to do this, but I would probably use `dplyr` package

If your data frame is called `structure`, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
structure %>% group_by(JVM) %>% summarize(cor = cor(trans,cpu))
```

Comment: it needs to be grouped by Server than JVM

Comment: does it need to be grouped by both?  Maybe give an example of what the result would should look like

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Cor = cor(trans,cpu)), by = JVM]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a correlation out of one data point but assuming that your real data has more data points per server/jvm try this code.  It does not use any packages:

```
out <- tapply(1:nrow(df), df[1:2], function(i) with(df[i, ], cor(cpu, trans)))
```

giving:

```
> out
           JVM
Server      JVM1 JVM2 JVM3 JVM4
  server101   NA   NA   NA   NA
  server102   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

If you prefer a long form then:

```
ftable(out, row.vars = 1:2)
```

giving:

```
Server    JVM     
server101 JVM1  NA
          JVM2  NA
          JVM3  NA
          JVM4  NA
server102 JVM1  NA
          JVM2  NA
          JVM3  NA
          JVM4  NA
```